# Scale data for Polynomial Regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, nonlinear-regression, splines, polynomial

I want to fit a polynomial model for the dataset which respondent variable is the length and the predictor variable is the Age. The dataset was recorded for 12 moths for the two years 1984 and 2010, and each month has its own value for different items recorded in that month which using their ID's. Different items are recorded in every data so this is not a longitudinal dataset. my Problem is i dont know what a proper scale of data to use in fitting the polynomial regression and ultimately the by B-spline since i believe it will model correctly the relation Here is the scatter plot of the relationship [image]ship.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean by scale? Are you talking about the units used for measuring your length and age variables?

Comment: I tried to fit the model using the current data format but i got erroneous results so i want to know what other alternative exist to fit the model, or I should convert the variables to the categorical ones and fit the model.?